# Python extract pattern matches

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression to extract words inside of a pattern.

I have some string that looks like this

```
someline abc
someother line
name my_user_name is valid
some more lines
```

I want to extract the word `my_user_name`. I do something like

```
import re
s = #that big string
p = re.compile("name .* is valid", re.flags)
p.match(s)  # this gives me <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x026B6838>
```

How do I extract `my_user_name` now?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

You need to capture from regex. `search` for the pattern, if found, retrieve the string using `group(index)`. Assuming valid checks are performed:

```
>>> p = re.compile("name (.*) is valid")
>>> result = p.search(s)
>>> result
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10555e738>
>>> result.group(1)     # group(1) will return the 1st capture (stuff within the brackets).
                        # group(0) will returned the entire matched text.
'my_user_name'
```

Comment: Are you sure that's not `group(0)` for the first match?

Comment: Kind of late, but both yes and no. `group(0)` returns the matched text, not the first capture group. The code comment is correct, while you seem to be confusing capture groups and matches. `group(1)` returns the first capture group.

Comment: this kind of questions should force a re-write of the documentation

Answer (score 99):

You can use matching groups:

```
p = re.compile('name (.*) is valid')
```

e.g.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('name (.*) is valid')
>>> s = """
... someline abc
... someother line
... name my_user_name is valid
... some more lines"""
>>> p.findall(s)
['my_user_name']
```

Here I use `re.findall` rather than `re.search` to get all instances of `my_user_name`.  Using `re.search`, you'd need to get the data from the group on the match object:

```
>>> p.search(s)   #gives a match object or None if no match is found
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xf5c60>
>>> p.search(s).group() #entire string that matched
'name my_user_name is valid'
>>> p.search(s).group(1) #first group that match in the string that matched
'my_user_name'
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, you might want to make your regex non-greedy:

```
p = re.compile('name (.*?) is valid')
```

to only pick up the stuff between `'name '` and the next `' is valid'` (rather than allowing your regex to pick up other `' is valid'` in your group.

Comment: It's possible a non-greedy match is required... (unless a username can be multiple words...)

Comment: @JonClements -- You mean `(.*?)`?  Yeah, that's possible, although not necessary unless OP us using `re.DOTALL`

Comment: yeah - `re.findall('name (.*) is valid', 'name jon clements is valid is valid is valid')` probably won't yield desired results...

Comment: This does not work for Python 2.7.1? It just prints a pattern object?

Comment: @CalmStorm -- Which part doesn't work (I tested on python2.7.3)?  The part where I use `.group` is exactly the same as the answer you accepted...

Comment: Ah... I was trying the findall which just gave me the entire string as a list. The group(1) works though

Answer (score 28):

You could use something like this:

```
import re
s = #that big string
# the parenthesis create a group with what was matched
# and '\w' matches only alphanumeric charactes
p = re.compile("name +(\w+) +is valid", re.flags)
# use search(), so the match doesn't have to happen 
# at the beginning of "big string"
m = p.search(s)
# search() returns a Match object with information about what was matched
if m:
    name = m.group(1)
else:
    raise Exception('name not found')
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use groups (indicated with `'('` and `')'`) to capture parts of the string. The match object's [`group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) method then gives you the group's contents:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'name my_user_name is valid'
>>> match = re.search('name (.*) is valid', s)
>>> match.group(0)  # the entire match
'name my_user_name is valid'
>>> match.group(1)  # the first parenthesized subgroup
'my_user_name'
```

In Python 3.6+ you can also [index](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.__getitem__) into a match object instead of using `group()`:

```
>>> match[0]  # the entire match 
'name my_user_name is valid'
>>> match[1]  # the first parenthesized subgroup
'my_user_name'
```

Answer (score 15):

Maybe that's a bit shorter and easier to understand:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '... someline abc... someother line... name my_user_name is valid.. some more lines'
>>> re.search('name (.*) is valid', text).group(1)
'my_user_name'
```

Answer (score 12):

You want a [capture group](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping).

```
p = re.compile("name (.*) is valid", re.flags) # parentheses for capture groups
print p.match(s).groups() # This gives you a tuple of your matches.
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's a way to do it without using groups (Python 3.6 or above):

```py
>>> re.search('2\d\d\d[01]\d[0-3]\d', 'report_20191207.xml')[0]
'20191207'
```

Comment: This addresses Python Regex, but doesn't address OP's specific question.

Comment: Besides, this basically adds nothing new to the existing answer(s) mentioning the 3.6+ indexing syntax.

Comment: It does not address the question specifically but this is actually a helpful answer

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a capture group `(?P<user>pattern)` and access the group like a dictionary `match['user']`.

```
string = '''someline abc\n
            someother line\n
            name my_user_name is valid\n
            some more lines\n'''

pattern = r'name (?P<user>.*) is valid'
matches = re.search(pattern, str(string), re.DOTALL)
print(matches['user'])

# my_user_name
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer via google because I wanted to **unpack** a `re.search()` result with **multiple groups** directly into multiple variables. While this might be obvious for some, it was not for me because I always used `group()` in the past, so maybe it helps someone in the future who also did not know about `group*s*()`.

```
s = "2020:12:30"
year, month, day = re.search(r"(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)", s).groups()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're actually trying to extract a name vice simply find a match. If this is the case, having span indexes for your match is helpful and I'd recommend using `re.finditer`. As a shortcut, you know the `name` part of your regex is length 5 and the `is valid` is length 9, so you can slice the matching text to extract the name.

*Note - In your example, it looks like `s` is string with line breaks, so that's what's assumed below.*

> ```
> ## covert s to list of strings separated by line:
> s2 = s.splitlines()
>
> ## find matches by line: 
> for i, j in enumerate(s2):
>     matches = re.finditer("name (.*) is valid", j)
>     ## ignore lines without a match
>     if matches:
>         ## loop through match group elements
>         for k in matches:
>             ## get text
>             match_txt = k.group(0)
>             ## get line span
>             match_span = k.span(0)
>             ## extract username
>             my_user_name = match_txt[5:-9]
>             ## compare with original text
>             print(f'Extracted Username: {my_user_name} - found on line {i}')
>             print('Match Text:', match_txt)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple solution to the problem

```
import re

except_substring = "\w+_\w+_\w+"
original_string = """someline abc
someother line
name my_user_name is valid
some more lines"""

m=re.findall(except_substring, original_string)
if m:
    print(m[0]) #--> "my_user_name"
else:
    print("Substring was not found")
```

Or we can make the function:

```
def replace_all_exept_substring(original_string: str, except_substring: str) -> str:

     """
     The function gets the substring to be skipped from the whole string
     can get it in the form of a single word, e.g. "NoSuchUser"
     or a regular expression, e.g. "Message.*has.been.*rejected."
     original_string : the whole phrase to search for
     except_substring : the phrase/word to be returned
     return : the message sent to the following e mail address has been rejected
     """
        
     m = re.findall(except_substring, original_string)
     # A+1 if A > B else A-1
     return m[0] if m else original_string
```

```
m=replace_all_exept_substring(original_string, except_substring)

print(m) #--> "my_user_name" or "original_string"
```