# Find string match pattern

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a pattern like this:

```
pattern = "Delivered to %(recipient)s at %(location)s"
```

How can I get the `recipient` and `location` of a string based on this pattern?

For example: `Delivered to Mr.Smith at Seattle` would be extracted to `[Mr.Smith,Seattle]`.

Hence, I want that any string that matches this pattern will extract these 2 parameters like this.

Comment: That's dublicate question of [Python extract pattern matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340582/python-extract-pattern-matches).

Comment: @Andriy a "dublicate" huh? Interesting.

Comment: @Andriy LOL. btw just giving you a hard time, didn't mean any offense. Merry christmas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

pattern = 'Delivered to Mr.Smith at Seattle'

re.match(r'Delivered to (.*) at (.*)', pattern).groups()
('Mr.Smith', 'Seattle')

re.findall(r'Delivered to (.*) at (.*)', pattern)
[('Mr.Smith', 'Seattle')]
```

Comment: 1. I think OP'd like use `re.findall()` in this case. 2. `.*` catchs all things after the string, I think maybe use `.+? `  (a space after this regex) instead.

Comment: What's re? Just curious?