# String pattern matching in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Similar to this question [Find string match pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460231/find-string-match-pattern/34460262#34460262) . But this time I want to do this in PostgreSQL.

I have tried :

```
Select * from my_table where my_param SIMILAR TO "Delivered to (.*) at (.*)"
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Checkout `LIKE` Statement for this purposes usefull explanations [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: Denys , sorry I have just edited the question , i have tried to use SIMILAR TO , not a plain one like before

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_matches` to extract part of text:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT col, regexp_matches(col, 'Delivered to (.*) at (.*)') AS r
  FROM tab
  -- WHERE col LIKE 'Delivered to % at %'
)
SELECT col, r[1] part1, r[2] part2
FROM cte;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/086d9/2/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║               col                 ║  part1    ║  part2  ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ Delivered to Mr.Smith at Seattle  ║ Mr.Smith  ║ Seattle ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

---

If you only want to find rows without extracting use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE col LIKE 'Delivered to % at %'
```