# Finding contracted word-pattern (*'*) in Igbo texts

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract words of the form `wor'word` in Igbo text using regex (I really don't know regex well). For example,

```
line = "jir’ọbara ya"
```

If I do

```
found = re.match("\w+’\w+", line)
print found.group()
```

I get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` instead of `jir’ọbara`

Then, if I do `found = re.match("\w+’|\w+", line)`, it gives me only `jir’`.

Any suggestion on how to fix this or best other way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: try `found.findall(line)` after compile command with yout first approach , read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340582/python-extract-pattern-matches

Comment: Thanks Singh. I guess the fault is diacritic xter (dot below) in 'o'. Got this error "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If format of the line is consistent then:

```
wor, word = line.split()[0].split("’")
```

or

```
>>> found = re.match("(\w+)’(\w+)", line)
>>> found.group(1)
'jir'
>>> found.group(2)
'ọbara'
>>>
```

Comment: No, the format of the line is not consistent.  I guess the fault is diacritic xter (dot below) in 'o'. Got this error "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: It gives me " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' ".

Comment: try to copy `’` from your string and paste it to regex. It works fine for me with your string.

Comment: I tried it in python 3, it works fine. But doesn't work in python 2.