# Split string using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have such string

```
Sale: \t\t\t5 Jan \u2013 10 Jan
```

I want to extract the start and the end of the sale. Very straightforward approach would be to make several spilts, but I want to that using regular expressions.
As the result I want to get

```
start = "5 Jan"
end = "10 Jan"
```

Is it possible to do that using regex?

Comment: [Yes it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340582/python-extract-pattern-matches).

Comment: @user202729 thanks, what is the pattern? I'm a bit confused about these unicode symbol

Comment: Will the start always be the first date and the end always the second date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help.

```
import re
s = "Sale: \t\t\t5 Jan \u2013 10 Jan"
f = re.findall(r"\d+ \w{3}", s)
print f
```

**Output**:

```
['5 Jan', '10 Jan']
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an optimised one but works assuming the string pattern remains the same.

```
import re
s = 'Sale: \t\t\t5 Jan \u2013 10 Jan'
start, end = re.search(r'Sale:(.*)', s).group(1).strip().replace('\u2013', ',').split(', ')

# start <- 5 Jan
# end <- 10 Jan
```