# Accessing specific values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[
{
  "GENERAL":{      "COMP_TYPE": "Turbine",
  "TEST_NUMBER": ""
 },
  "IMPELLER": {
  "INDUCER_DIAM": "",
  "INERTIA": null
 }, 
  "CUSTOM": {},
  "BOUNDS": {},
     "FILES": [
  {
    "FILE_DATA": "FILE_NAME": "A130_H65_TV11_TT12_TA28.sae"
  },
  {
    "FILE_DATA": "FILE_NAME": "A130_H65_TV11_TT12_TA28.saeT"
  },
  {
    "FILE_DATA": "\n\n1        UI4.22.06\n 537  65   1.0000   0.037053.234         101  0.00000  0.00000\n       "FILE_NAME": "A130_H65_TV11_TT12_TA28.tr1"
  }
 ]
};
{ 
  "GENERAL": {
  "COMP_TYPE": "Turbine",
  "TEST_NUMBER": ""
},
"IMPELLER": {
  "INDUCER_DIAM": "",
  "INERTIA": null
},
"CUSTOM": {},
"BOUNDS": {},
"FILES": [
  {
    "FILE_DATA": "FILE_NAME": "A130_H65_TV11_TT12_TA28.sae"
  },
  {
    "FILE_DATA": "FILE_NAME": "A130_H65_TV11_TT12_TA28.saeT"
  },
  {
    "FILE_DATA": "\n\n1        UI4.22.06\n 537  65   1.0000   0.037053.234         101  0.00000  0.00000\n       "FILE_NAME": "A130_H65_TV11_TT12_TA28.tr1"
  }
]
}
]
```

My JSON file contains several dictionaries within a list as shown above which I trimmed down for this purpose. I'm trying to access the data inside the 3rd "FILE_DATA" of every "FILES". Specifically trying to get the first two numbers in each case that is 537 and 65 here.

I was able to loop through the list and access all of the data in the 3rd "FILE_DATA" but couldn't figure out how to get to only the first two numbers in them.

```
with open(turbine_json_path, "r") as f:
    turbine = json.load(f)
    for d in turbine:
        print(d["FILES"][2]["FILE_DATA"])
```

Sorry for this basic question. I tried all sorts of tricks before asking this question.

Comment: I suggest using RegEx:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340582/python-extract-pattern-matches

Comment: Your JSON file is very complicated to read through, but it is a mix of dictionaries and lists, so what you should do is go through, and identify which item in each list you want to follow and call that number (including the first list, which you may need to call element 0 of), and then the key of each dictionary, but you can do that directly without a loop if you follow the chain of objects.

Comment: `{
    "FILE_DATA": "FILE_NAME": "A130_H65_TV11_TT12_TA28.sae"
  },` is not a valid JSON object.

Comment: Using consistent indentation and newlines does wonders for making the structure of both the JSON and the decoded data structure clear.