# How to get one column of a text file

Tags: python

I have a txt file which contains different types of readings. I would like to display minimum, maximum and average value of one of the readings.

an example output of the txt file is

```
19-05-2020 17:23:15|25.10c,52.00%rh
19-05-2020 17:23:15|25.10c,53.00%rh
19-05-2020 17:23:15|25.20c,54.00%rh
19-05-2020 17:23:15|25.30c,55.00%rh
```

I would like to display the minimum and maximum value of the celsius readings only.

I have the code down below but it reads the entire file. I want it to read-only celsius readings.

```
_min = None
_max = None
_sum = 0
_len = 0
with open('numaralar.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        val = int(line.strip())
        if _min is None or val < _min:
            _min = val
        if _max is None or val > _max:
            _max = val
        _sum += val
        _len += 1

_avg = float(_sum) / _len

# Print output
print("Min: %s" % _min)  
print("Max: %s" % _max)  
print("Avg: %s" % _avg)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I like that you've mentioned what you've done but I think it would be better to clarify that in the text file, the columns are timestamps, temperature readings, and relative humidity. One can figure it out in this case, but it may be less obvious in other contexts.

Comment: You already know how to get the min and max, but what you're really asking is how to get the temperature readings, so I've fixed the title for you. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Also I just noticed you tried to bold the Celsius column but bold doesn't work in preformatted text so I fixed that for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of getting the values, using regex

```
import re

# Extract the details present inside "|(26.7)c" and convert to float.
with open("numaralar.txt") as f:
    # "re.findall" extracts all the values that match the pattern
    vals = [float(x) for x in re.findall("\|(.*)c", f.read())]
# vals = [25.1, 25.1, 25.2, 25.3]

# Use in-built function to get the required values.
print("Min:", min(vals))
print("Max:", max(vals))
print("Avg:", sum(vals)/len(vals))
```

Comment: Hey, the user seems new. Could you explain each line of the code?

Comment: Thanks for your code when I try it the output I get is  <built-in function max>
<built-in function min> you know how I can solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use regular expression to extract celcius reading, something like this.

```
[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{2}c
```

Then remove 'c' and turn it into float. Then you can do another operations on that data.

Regular expression can be used to extract specific piece of string which has some pattern. In your example - numbers, dot, numbers, "c".

Above pattern means:

- [0-9]{1,} - one or more numbers
- . - then one dot (we use escape sign, because only dot in regex means "any sign")
- [0-9]{2} - then two numbers
- c - sign "c" in the end

See here how to extract such data with **re** module.
[Python extract pattern matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340582/python-extract-pattern-matches/15340694)

```py
readings = [
  '19-05-2020 17:23:15|25.10c,52.00%rh',
  '19-05-2020 17:23:15|25.10c,53.00%rh',
  '19-05-2020 17:23:15|25.20c,54.00%rh',
  '19-05-2020 17:23:15|25.30c,55.00%rh'
]

import re

temperatures = []

for reading in readings:
  pattern = re.compile('[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{2}c')
  temperature = pattern.search(reading).group(0)
  temperature = temperature[:-1] #removes last character which is "c"
  temperature = float(temperature)
  temperatures.append(temperature)

print(temperatures)
```

Comment: How do you use this? Keep in mind OP seems new, so you might need to explain what regex is, and how to use it. LMK when you clarify and I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: @AbdullahErgun is this clear enough? I recommend to read more about regex, because it's really powerful to extract some data from complex string when you know pattern.

Comment: @wojtek2kdev yes it is I have short it out thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without regex, but it's a bit of a pain. You have to split on the pipe `|` and get everything after, then split that on the `c` and get everything before.

Borrowing from [Sushanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4985099/sushanth)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61975685/4518341):

```
with open("numaralar.txt") as f:
    vals = [float(line.split('|')[1].split('c')[0]) for line in f]
# vals = [25.1, 25.1, 25.2, 25.3]

# Use in-built function to get the required values.
print("Min:", min(vals))
print("Max:", max(vals))
print("Avg:", sum(vals)/len(vals))
```

Although, splitting makes more sense when you're processing all the columns, e.g.:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        time, data = line.strip().split('|')
        temp, humidity = data.split(',')
        temp = float(temp.rstrip('c'))
        humidity = float(humidity.rstrip('%rh'))
        print(time, temp, humidity)
```