# Using finditer as performant regex splitter

Tags: python, regex

I have large strings that look similar to this (it is only an excerpt, of course):

```py
content = "78934789;;;;foo foo bar bar;;;;ping pong;;;\n\n\n78923456901;;;;Some more text;;;;;\n\n\n187894;;;;Number 12345 should not match;;;;\n\n\n123456 \n\n\nthis should be included;;;;;;\n\n\n"
```

and I want to return as performant as possible only the substrings that start with a number from 6 to 11 characters long and go to the next of this number or just to the end if such a number cannot be found any more.

So the text consists of any characters (including newlines and other special characters) and the only reliable separator is a number between 6 and 11 characters long. At this separator the text is to be split to start further processing. The processing happens within a web application and should run as an independent thread. Therefore, it would be useful if the substring matches came back iterable.

So I think that [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) is what I need, but I have problems getting this working. I've tried a lot. The version that comes closest to my wanted result is using a regex with a lookahead assertion `/(?=\d{6,11}).*/` together with `re.finditer()`, see:

```py
In [1]: import re                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
In [2]: content = "78934789;;;;foo foo bar bar;;;;ping pong;;;\n\n\n78923456901;;;;Some more text;;;;;\n\n\n187894;;;;Number 12345 should not match;;;;\n\n\n123456 \n\n\nthis should be included;;;;;;\n\n\n"                                
In [3]: pattern = re.compile(r"(?=\d{6,11}).*")                                                                                                                                                                                               
In [4]: for item in re.finditer(pattern, content): 
   ...:     print(item) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
<re.Match object; span=(0, 43), match='78934789;;;;foo foo bar bar;;;;ping pong;;;'>
<re.Match object; span=(46, 80), match='78923456901;;;;Some more text;;;;;'>
<re.Match object; span=(83, 126), match='187894;;;;Number 12345 should not match;;;;'>
<re.Match object; span=(129, 136), match='123456 '>
```

But the newlines and the rest of the `content` string are not included. I've played a bit with flags like `re.DOTALL` or `re.MULTILINE`, and even with [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library which supports lookup assertions with variable lengths. Everything without success, so I'm stuck on this point.

To be as exact as possible, these are the substrings for given content string, a generator should return/yield:

```
"78934789;;;;foo foo bar bar;;;;ping pong;;;\n\n\n"
"78923456901;;;;Some more text;;;;;\n\n\n"
"187894;;;;Number 12345 should not match;;;;\n\n\n"
"123456 \n\n\nthis should be included;;;;;;\n\n\n"
```

As you can see in my approach above, newline characters are not included, and using a `re.DOTALL` flag in my approach would lead to an unwanted behaviour, that `.*` will match too much, then.

What I want to know is: Is this possible using a regular expression and to be also performant (i.e. not iterating twice over the string) or should I better write my own generator function, instead (eventually a bit more complex)?

Comment: To access the whole match value use `print(item.group())`. Also, if you need to match line breaks with `.`, use `re.DOTALL` (you say you used it, so I guess that is not the problem here).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't see how this is helpful for me, I've said that I played also with `re.DOTALL`. So e.g. using `pattern = re.compile(r"(?=\d{6,11}).*", re.DOTALL)` and then `for item in re.finditer(pattern, content): print(item.group())` does not work. I also do not see how https://stackoverflow.com/q/15340582/2648551 is helpful for my problem? If it is, I need more help here.

Comment: Then what is the problem? You have https://regex101.com/r/Bw2VGI/1. What do you want? Your code shows clearly you do not know how to get the matched text. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15340694/3832970 shows you how to do it. Now, you may go on with your work.

Comment: I have also written: *But the newlines and the rest of the content string are not included.* - So I want also the newlines to be included! And using `re.DOTALL` leads to one result only, because `.*` is matching too much, then. So my idea was to use a lookahead for that, but it is simply not working.

Comment: Please update your question. Include what matches you expect and a valid attempt at obtaining them.

Comment: Do not post new questions, editing is fine. Try `re.findall(r'^\d{6,11}\b.*(?:\n(?!\d{6,11}\b).*)*', content, flags=re.M)`, like in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/OIEO8T/1), or [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/rkDROV).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104404/how-can-i-performantly-use-a-pattern-to-return-substrings-of-a-text-including-a?noredirect=1#comment109841050_62104404) from [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) finally solved my problem. He suggested to use something like this: `re.findall(r'^\d{6,11}\b.*(?:\n(?!\d{6,11}\b).*)*', content, flags=re.M)` and provided it also via [regex demo page](https://regex101.com/r/OIEO8T/1) and [python demo page](https://ideone.com/rkDROV).

What I missed is that using a *negative lookahead assertion* `(?!...)` will be needed to restrict `.*` matching too much. With that it was easy to reformulate it using [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html%5C#re.finditer):

```py
import re
from typing import Iterable, Optional, Pattern, Union

case_pattern = re.compile(
    rf""" 
    \d{6,11}             # case number
    (?s:.(?!\d{6,11}))*  # all until next case 
    .*\n*                # rest for last match 
    """, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE
)

def split_generator(text: str, pattern: Optional[Union[Pattern, str]] = " ") -> Iterable[str]:
    """Split given text on regex pattern (default: " ")

    A given text (str) is split according to a given regex pattern. If no
    pattern is given, a default is used that simply splits the text at every
    single space.

    This is a generator iterator function that tries to be as performant as
    possible, i.e. iterates over the text only once and only temporarily
    stores parts of the text (the split elements) while yielding them.

    :param text: The text on which the split will be performed
    :param pattern: A regex pattern that will applied as separator
    :return: An iterator which will yield each split item
    """
    yield from (el.group() for el in re.finditer(pattern, text))
```

This seems to be less performant as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62106286/2648551) from [Martin P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6593069/martin-p), because of the expensive negative lookahead constraint in the regex. But it handles the memory consumption much better without the need to save something. The regex can probably be optimized, though.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

```
import re
def splitter(content):
    pieces = re.split(r'(\d{6,11})', content)  # split at the delimiter
    pieces = filter(bool, pieces)  # filter empty items
    yield from [item + next(pieces, '') for item in pieces]  # combine every two items
```

With the result:

```
>>> content = "78934789;;;;foo foo bar bar;;;;ping pong;;;\n\n\n78923456901;;;;Some more text;;;;;\n\n\n187894;;;;Number 12345 should not match;;;;\n\n\n123456 \n\n\nthis should be included;;;;;;\n\n\n"
>>> gen = splitter(content)
>>> list(gen)
['78934789;;;;foo foo bar bar;;;;ping pong;;;\n\n\n', '78923456901;;;;Some more text;;;;;\n\n\n', '187894;;;;Number 12345 should not match;;;;\n\n\n', '123456 \n\n\nthis should be included;;;;;;\n\n\n']
```

Comment: Don't you iterate on that twice? I like the readabilty (+1), but don't like the memory consumption (because the pieces have to be saved) and also the filter function.