# regex in python not give full output

Tags: python, regex, string

I have problem with search in regex in python.

Some part of text look like this:

```
<h3 class="space">Status ogłoszenia</h3>
<div class="under-space gray-row">Aktualne</div>
```

I want to find word in place of 'Aktualne' It can be many different words.
So i search for second line.

I have written some regex code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'lxml')

r = re.search("Status ogłoszenia</h3>\n(.)*</div>", str(soup))

r = str(r)
```

In output I have:

```
'<re.Match object; span=(7128, 7199), match=\'Status ogłoszenia</h3>\\n<div class="under-space g>'
```

So it's not full output. Some part is missing.

How to change this code to have full output or it is some unknown for me regex behavior.

Comment: Don't call `str(r)`. YOu'd use the methods within the object `r`. In this case, try: `print(r.group(1))`. Here's my [answer that might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15340694/227884)

Comment: Can you turn this into a short, running example?

Comment: Why not call `soup.find('h3').find_next('div').text`?

Comment: because there's about 200 lines like this on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `search()` returns a `MatchObject`, so here's what you do:

```py
matchobject = re.search("Status ogłoszenia</h3>\n.*</div>", str(soup))
print(matchobject[0])
```