# I dont know why it doesnt read my Mac adress

Tags: python, mac-address

I'm starting to learn coding in python. I'm making an udemy course, where i have to make a program that reads the Mac Address in kali-linux with python2 and 3.
The only problem that I have is that my re.search command doesn't read my old Mac Address to the end changing it. I really think that the code is fine. So here it is, hope someone helps me.

---

```
def get_current_mac(interface):
    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", interface])
    mac_address_search_result = re.search(r" \w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w ", ifconfig_result)

    if mac_address_search_result:
        return mac_address_search_result
    else:
        print(" Could not read Mac Address ")
```

And here is the error that appears:

```
Current mac =<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f7ebbf22ab0>

Changing MAC address for eth0 to 11:22:33:44:44:11

SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address

Error, try again
```

Thank you, i really hope to get some help with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Python extract pattern matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340582/python-extract-pattern-matches)

Comment: The crucial error appears to come from code which you are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

`re.search` returns a `Match` object. If you want the matched string:

```
if mac_address_search_result:
    return mac_address_search_result.group(0)
```