# Extract token from within <script> tags BeautifulSoup4, Requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing, python-3.9

I'm trying to isolate the securityToken from an HTML response.  The securityToken is within  tags though.

I've been able to isolate the tag with the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://obe.sandals.com/read-land-availability/'
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"})
soup= BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
mytext = soup.find('script', text = re.compile('securityToken:'))

print(mytext)
```

Here is the output, but I cannot figure out the last step to extract the securityToken

```
<script> window._app.page = { jsView: './views/step1/Vacation', securityToken: "BF8394B1DD5481AF43BE2AF02243903F121D26327E83ADC13785F6EF739B5870", subSessionId: "6D71C585C7F51CF105B3100A473635ACF3637329F2C1ABAADB1F2827832562D8", step: 1 }; </script>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract the substring between two markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666973/how-to-extract-the-substring-between-two-markers)

Comment: or [Python extract pattern matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340582/python-extract-pattern-matches/15340694)

Comment: Yes, both of the links point in the correct direction for a solution.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the value of `securityToken` try the following:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://obe.sandals.com/read-land-availability/'
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
mytext = soup.find('script', text = re.compile('securityToken:'))


print(re.search(r'securityToken: "(.*?)"', str(mytext)).group(1))
```

Output:

```
5EFDCE1D62C5F1C1369EF3629F921B0F90301ACB51C5FD24321D7FB58D04DE50
```

Comment: That worked!  I did not think to structure the search that way.  Thank you!! @MendelG

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'html5lib' instead of 'html.parser', and the location of the security token is always the same:

```py
mytext.split('securityToken: "')[1].split('", subSessionId:')[0]
```