# Deleting characters in csv cell

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to delete characters in a .csv file that is before and follows a string of numbers.

```
 | Description                                     |
 | ----------------------------------------------- |
 | Case Number and Notes: 21-12311 check building  |
 | Case Number and Notes: 10-50 w/c , 21-10411     |
 | Case Number and Notes: 21-10421 , Vehicle Maint |
 | Case Number and Notes: Test                     |
 | Case Number and Notes: 21-9693 , traffic Maint  |
```

I need to delete all characters in this column that come before and after the 21-#####. Is this possible to do?

Eventually I'd also like to have a couple leading zeros after the dash to make the number the same length, but I'm still working on that.

Results should be

```
| 21-12311 |
| 21-10411 |
| 21-10421 |
| 21-9693  |
```

Comment: What exactly should be the result in this case?

Comment: See above for edit for results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python extract pattern matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340582/python-extract-pattern-matches)

Comment: Partially, however, I need to get it from a csv file.

Comment: Why not use the `csv` module to read the file?

Comment: what did you try? where is your code?

Comment: if every text start with `Case Number and Notes: ` then you can remove it using replace or slice text `[23:]` or you can `split(": ")` and get second part. And similar with text after number - you can `split(" ")` and get first element, later you have to only check if it starts with `21-`

Comment: if you `split('-')` text `21-9693`  then you can format back using string-formatting or other functions to add zeros - `parts = "21-9693".split('-')`, `print( f"{parts[0]}-{parts[1].zfill(6)}" )` gives `21-009693'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to extract possible case numbers. In the case of your 3rd row, you can take the last possible match per row.

For example:

```py
import csv
import re

re_casenum = re.compile(r'\b(\d+-\d+)\b')

with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=csv_input.fieldnames + ['Case Number'])
    csv_output.writeheader()
    
    for row in csv_input:
        description = row['Description']
        case_numbers = re_casenum.findall(description)
        
        if case_numbers:
            row['Case Number'] = case_numbers[-1]
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This would give you a `output.csv` containing:

```
Description,Case Number
Case Number and Notes: 21-12311 check building,21-12311
"Case Number and Notes: 10-50 w/c , 21-10411",21-10411
"Case Number and Notes: 21-10421 , Vehicle Maint",21-10421
"Case Number and Notes: 21-9693 , traffic Maint",21-9693
```

This would add a new `Case Number` column to your CSV. Note, from your example it is not clear what delimiter is used for your CSV file, you might need to add suitable `delimiter=';'` type parameters. The quotes are added as there is a comma in the field.